# Correct way of sending and receiving text/plain with fetch

Tags: http, fetch

What is the right syntax to POST and receive plain text using *fetch*?

This is my code :

```
fetch('http://localhost:3000/postendpoint', {
      method: 'POST',
      mode: 'no-cors',
      headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
      },
      body: 'hello world'
      }).then(function(response) {
        return response.text()
      }).then(function(data) {
        console.log("data ", data)
      }).catch(function(err){ 
         console.log("An error occurred")
      });
```

When I do it with curl the app replies with text with no issues and I can see in the developer console everything is fine, but my app does not log anything. I only get :

```
data
```

But no actual text after that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `no-cors` means you will not be able to read the response body. This is by design, don't use `no-cors`.

If you would like more background, I wrote this: https://evertpot.com/no-cors/

Comment: Thanks so much. This is an amazing response.